# Choice of data structure to contain last 5 minutes of long continuous data stream

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, queues

Let's assume that I am continuously receiving big amount of data. For example, this millisecond I get 100 numbers, next millisecond I get another 500 numbers, after that I might get nothing for a several milliseconds and then again get some numbers in the next millisecond. Also assume that this process lasts for weeks. However, I don't really need to save old data in memory. What I really need is to remember data received in the last 5 minutes. That is, all I want is to be able to present data for last 5 minutes whenever I am asked to.

Do you have any ideas on how to realize this? What kind of data structure would help in such a situation and how should I use it? All I could imagine was saving with every piece of data the moment of time when it was received, storing everything in a queue and constantly deleting element from queue's head if its time shows that it was received more than 5 minutes ago. I hope there is a more elegant/efficient solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that your solution is inelegant/inefficient?

Comment: idk, I just quickly improvised that. It seems that this kind of problem must be very popular in the industry (HFT etc.), thus I concluded that for years there must have been introduced some super clever ways to work with this.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you are looking for is [double-ended queue (deque)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). It is basically what you have imagined, with the extra ease of operations on the front.

Deque has been implemented in [many languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Operations) in [their standard libraries or packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Language_support), with some extra operations available for practical convenience usually. For example, you can access any element by an index in a deque in C++ or Python implementation (that index is the number of elements before the element accessed).

Comment: But in which way is it better than queue in my problem? It seems to me that I would still use one end for inserting elements and another for deleting them, therefore not using this double-endedness.